# Change manual id to id of database table

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I use codeigniter framework.

I want this number id 1 to be changed to the existing id in the database table, how to do it?.

```
$nik_id = 1;
```

Beranda_model.php

```
public function getPost() 
  {

    // lets assume a user is logged in with id $nik_id
    $nik_id = 1;

    // if user clicks like or dislike button
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
      $pengaduan_id = $_POST['pengaduan_id'];
      $action = $_POST['action'];
      switch ($action) {
        case 'like':
             $sql="INSERT INTO like_dislike (nik_id, pengaduan_id, rating_action) 
                 VALUES ($nik_id, $pengaduan_id, 'like') 
                 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating_action='like'";
             break;
        case 'dislike':
              $sql="INSERT INTO like_dislike (nik_id, pengaduan_id, rating_action) 
                   VALUES ($nik_id, $pengaduan_id, 'dislike') 
                 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating_action='dislike'";
             break;
        case 'unlike':
            $sql="DELETE FROM like_dislike WHERE nik_id=$nik_id AND pengaduan_id=$pengaduan_id";
            break;
        case 'undislike':
              $sql="DELETE FROM like_dislike WHERE nik_id=$nik_id AND pengaduan_id=$pengaduan_id";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

        $this->db->query($sql);
        echo Self::getRating($pengaduan_id);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Get total number of likes for a particular post
    function getLikes($id_pengaduan)
    {

      $ci =& get_instance();
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='like'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql)->result_array();
      return implode($rs[0]);
    }

   // Get total number of dislikes for a particular post
    function getDislikes($id_pengaduan)
    {
      $ci =& get_instance();
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike 
            WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='dislike'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql)->result_array();
      return implode($rs[0]);
    }

    // Get total number of likes and dislikes for a particular post
    function getRating($id_pengaduan)
    {
      $ci =& get_instance();
      $rating = array();
      $likes_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='like'";
      $dislikes_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike 
                WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='dislike'";
      $likes_rs = $ci->db->query($likes_query)->result_array();
      $dislikes_rs =$ci->db->query($dislikes_query)->result_array();
      $rating = [
        'likes' =>  implode($likes_rs[0]),
        'dislikes' => implode($dislikes_rs[0])
      ];
      return json_encode($rating);
    }

    // Check if user already likes post or not
    function userLiked($pengaduan_id)
    {

      $ci =& get_instance();
      $nik_id = 1;
      $sql ="SELECT * FROM like_dislike WHERE nik_id=$nik_id AND pengaduan_id=$pengaduan_id AND rating_action='like'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql);
      if ($rs->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

  // Check if user already dislikes post or not
  function userDisliked($pengaduan_id)
  {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $nik_id = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM like_dislike WHERE nik_id=$nik_id AND pengaduan_id=$pengaduan_id AND rating_action='dislike'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql);
      if ($rs->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }

    $sql = "SELECT `tanggapan`.*, `pengaduan`.*, `petugas`.*
                  FROM `tanggapan` JOIN `pengaduan`
                  ON `tanggapan`.`id_pengaduan` = `pengaduan`.`id_pengaduan` 
                  JOIN `petugas` ON `tanggapan`.`id_petugas` = `petugas`.`id_petugas`
                ";
            
      $data_pengaduan = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $data_pengaduan;

  }

  // Private Function Like Dislike
   private static function getLikes($id_pengaduan)
    {
      $ci =& get_instance();
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='like'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql)->result_array();
      return implode($rs[0]);
    }

    private static function getDislikes($id_pengaduan)
    {
      $ci =& get_instance();
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike 
            WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='dislike'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql)->result_array();
      return implode($rs[0]);
    }

    private static function getRating($id_pengaduan)
    {
      $ci =& get_instance();
      $rating = array();
      $likes_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='like'";
      $dislikes_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_dislike 
                WHERE pengaduan_id = $id_pengaduan AND rating_action='dislike'";
      $likes_rs = $ci->db->query($likes_query)->result_array();
      $dislikes_rs =$ci->db->query($dislikes_query)->result_array();
      $rating = [
        'likes' =>  implode($likes_rs[0]),
        'dislikes' => implode($dislikes_rs[0])
      ];
      return json_encode($rating);
    }

    private static function userLiked($pengaduan_id)
    {
      $ci =& get_instance();
      $nik_id = 1;
      $sql ="SELECT * FROM like_dislike WHERE nik_id=$nik_id AND pengaduan_id=$pengaduan_id AND rating_action='like'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql);
      if ($rs->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    private static function userDisliked($pengaduan_id)
    {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $nik_id = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM like_dislike WHERE nik_id=$nik_id AND pengaduan_id=$pengaduan_id AND rating_action='dislike'";
      $rs = $ci->db->query($sql);
      if ($rs->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: 'nik_id' is primary key in your database table ?

Comment: It’s hard to understand what you are trying to do without seeming the structure of the relevant table/s in your database. Could you share the columns that you have and specify which one is the “id”?

Comment: Table masyarakat
nik is primary key char(16)

Table like_dislike
nik_id is foreign key char(16)


i want to fetch nik data from masyarakat table, i use nik as id.

Comment: So those who can like and dislike posts are users who are in the masyarakat table, and their nik will be stored in the like_dislike table, to be precise in the nik_id column.